# Кто в рамках clean architecture отвечает за состояние прогресс бара?

Tags: android, архитектура, rxjava

Кейс: Нужно показывать прогресс бар, когда свежие данные грузятся с сервера.

На UI данные попадают из БД. В БД из сети. 
Сначала нужно показать имеющиеся данные, сходить в сети за свежими и после этого обновить их на UI.

Если состоянием прогресс бара будет рулить презентер, то как он узнает, что после первой порции данных (от БД) не нужно скрывать прогресс,а после второй нужно?
А что если эти же данные нужно обновить по внешнему триггеру (пуш например пришел)? В таком случает презентер текущего экрана вообще не узнает ДО получения данных, о том что они сейчас загружаются..

Может ли в таком случает интерактор и репозиторий рулить состоянием прогресса, и уведомлять об этом презентер?

Какие еще есть варианты и как в такой ситуации поступаете вы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил объединить 2 варианта предложенных вышел и получил вот такой 
[класс помощник](https://github.com/MrVilkaman/cleanbase/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/mrvilkaman/datalayer/tools/RxLoadWrapperHolder.java). 
[Примеры](https://github.com/MrVilkaman/cleanbase/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/github/mrvilkaman/datalayer/tools/RxLoadWrapperHolderTest.java) использования в виде тестов.

Если в двух словах, то с помощью этого класс данные оборачиваются в [контейнер](https://github.com/MrVilkaman/cleanbase/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/mrvilkaman/domainlayer/models/DataErrorWrapper.java) который может содержать данные\ошибку\состояние прогресса

1) С помощью метода `modifySingle` можно завернуть "конечный"\единичный `Observable` который в конце работы вызывает `onComplete` \ `onError`.

Например это запрос через Retroit.

2) А с помощью метода `modifyStream` можно завернуть "бесконечный" `Observable` который просто выдает данные в `onNext` и никогда не вызывает `onComplete` \ `onError`.

Например, это может пригодится когда данные на UI всегда отдаются из БД, а от retrofit обновляют в БД,  тогда `modifyStream` преобразуется поток данных из БД, а слушатель `bindToLoad` вешается на `retrofit` запрос.
Последний как раз и определяет когда нужно показать\скрыть прогресс бар и "прокинуть" ошибку от `retrofit` на UI не нарушая дальнейшей работы потока.

И для подписке на UI можно использовать [шаблон](https://github.com/MrVilkaman/cleanbase/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/mrvilkaman/presentationlayer/subscriber/StreamSubscriber.java) Subscriber который выглядит примерно так:

```
public void onNext(DataErrorWrapper<D> wrap) {
    if (wrap.isSuccess()) {
        onNextValue(wrap.getValue());
    }
    if (wrap.isError()) {
        onError(wrap.getThrowable());
    }

    if (wrap.isProgress()) {
        showProgress();
    } else {
        hideProgress();
    }
}

public void onNextValue(D value) {
// работа с данными 
}
```

Получилось весьма удобно и автоматизированно) modifySingle\modifyStream\bindToLoad имеют версии для использования с  `compose`

Answer (score 2):

Оборачиваешь свою модель данных в модель со стейтом. Интерактор гоняет репозитории (в бд, сеть, кэш или куда тебе нужно) и пробрасывает в `onNext()` эту модель, в презентере(подписанном на интерактор) код в будет выглядеть примерно так

```
.subcribe(model ->{
    switch(model.getState){
        case INITIAL:
            view.showProgressBar()
        case LOADED_FROM_DB:
            //doSomething
        case LOADED_FROM_NETWORK:
            //doSomething
        case ERROR:
            //handleError
    }
})
```

События с пушем, мне кажется, выходят за рамки этого кейса, на них я бы отдельно подписывался, но при желании можешь добавить еще 1 стэйт)

Comment: В общем-то это больше похоже на то, что мне нужно. Даже немного излишне) мне не важно знать откуда данные) просто нужно знать что они еще в пути и скоро придут) Но Вас пример можно к этом приспособить) спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, не стоит перемешивать логику слоев. Репозитории - это объекты для манипуляции с данными, интеракторы - это какие-то сервисные классы, View - это UI.

Как вариант, можно использовать ту же схему, что предложили Александр Блинов с Евгением Мацюком на недавнем Mobius-е.

Делаем репозиторий, отдающий контейнер с нужными вам флагами и данными

```
class MyDataContainer(val isFromDatabase: Boolean,
                      val error: Throwable?,
                      val isFromPushNotification: Boolean) // etc
```

Наружу репозитория торчит Observable с этим контейнером. Презентер подписывается на его обновления и анализирует, как именно нужно изменить View. А вот репозиторий уже должен решать и понимать, откуда ему брать данные, какой в итоге контейнер сформировать.

Comment: Про контейнер идея понятна, но флаг о том что данные пришли из сети\бд мне придет вмести с данными, скажет через 2 секунды после начала, но 2 секунды програсс бар уже должен был отображаться.. 

либо я Вас не правильно понял..

Comment: @ЗахарЗолотарёв, не вопрос - вы делаете так, чтобы первым элементом этого Observable всегда эмитился какой-то спец элемент, по которому вы поймете, что надо отобразить самое первое состояние progress bar-а. 
В RxJava есть оператор `startWith`.